# Cannot cast expression in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have table with field AccountId, which type is DT_NTEXT. I need to cast it to DT_GUID

I use transformation "Derived Column". Expression is (DT_GUID)[AccountId]

But SSIS throw an error TITLE: **Cannot cast expression "(DT_GUID)AccountId" from data type "DT_NTEXT" to data type "DT_GUID". The requested cast is not supported.**

May be there is some workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a series of casts. I'm guessing it's something like DT_NEXT -> DT_WSTR -> DT_GUID

Comment: thanks, I did it yesterday, but I haven't close this ask here. You are right =)